# Using kuhn tucker to solve non negativity constraints

Tags: optimization, economics, karush-kuhn-tucker, utility

George likes breakfast tacos and milk. His utility is given by $u(t, m) = t + 5 \ln(m)$. Suppose tacos
and milk both cost 1 dollar a piece. How should George spend the $\$4$ he has set aside for breakfast?

I know I need to use kuhn-tucker conditions, but I am confused how this process works with non-negativity constraints of $t ≥ 0$ and $m ≥ 0$.

Comment: What kind of constraints do you know how to handle? Can you write the non-negativity constraints in a way that makes them similar to the constraints you can use?

Comment: Why do you want to use KKT and not Lagrange?

Comment: i do want to use lagrange.  if you use lagrange you get a negative number which is breaking the constraint.  I wish to learn how to navigate around this problem to find the answer.

Comment: If you ignore the nonnegativity constraints and the stationary point of the Lagrangian is outside the constraint set (i.e. violates one of your non-negativity constraints), then the solution (given one exists) must be when $t=0$ (it cannot be $m=0$, because that is not in the constraint set; the utility function is not defined at $m=0$).